# Eclipse Helios crash after centos upgrade to 6.5

Tags: eclipse

I upgraded my OS from Centos 6.3 to Centos 6.5 and now Eclise is crashing with the following:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000341be0e02c, pid=21970, tid=140559147611904
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b02) (build 1.7.0_51-mockbuild_2014_01_15_01_39-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xe02c]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /var/log/httpd/core or core.21970
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-21970/hs_error.log
#
```

Please let me know what should I do.

Thanks

Comment: Unzip a new Eclipse Helios, install Centos 6.3 and hope you can recover.  Never, ever upgrade any part of an Eclipse installation.  Always, always lay down a new Eclipse before you try and upgrade anything.

Comment: Will Eclipse not work with Centos 6.5?

Comment: I have no idea.  Try it on a different Eclipse than the one you develop with.  Never ever upgrade the Eclipse that you develop with.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this problem. The reason I found is the following : 6.5 is installing by default Firefox 17. Firefox has a dependency to xulrunner. The version of xulrunner is now with the same number as firefox so we have a xulrunner 17.

Check this : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383896

You see that eclipse is supporting xulrunner up to version 10. Downgrading Firefox and xulrunner to version 10 has fixed this crash for me.